# sandbox environment testing gives DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION error

Tags: testing, paypal, transactions, duplicates, sandbox

I am trying to integrate PayPal payments in my android app. At first it worked fine, but now it gives DUPLICATE TRANSACTION error every time i run test with fake sandbox accounts. Anyone knows how to resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, PayPal accounts block payments with a duplicate entry in the InvoiceID or Invoice Number field. This is to prevent systems or customers from accidentally paying for the same order # twice.  So, there are two solutions:

1. Ensure you always use a unique entry in the invoice # field, for every new transaction.
2. Disable the protection that blocks payments with a duplicate invoice #, within the receiving PayPal account's settings

   - Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/paymentPreferences
   - Live: https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/paymentPreferences

The use of disabling the option in (2.) is really never recommended, and resorting to it suggests your implementation or bookkeeping is poor. But the option is there if you really do need it.

(For multi-store solutions, i.e. if you have multiple stores that might have similar order numbers going into the same PayPal account and hence get crossover, a better solution would be for each store to have e.g. a 3 letter prefix before its order number, and use that compound identifier in the Invoice ID field.)

Comment: oh! what a silly mistake! i hard coded the invoice number!! :D so, all transactions were having the same number. thank you!!